# how can i print/echo array keys and values contain in stdClass object and send the values to my mail?

Tags: php

I need keys and values to extract and send to my mail:

as name:sam
        email:sam@qwe.com     contact no: 555555555

```
Array (    
 [0] => stdClass Object
          (
           [key] => Name:
           [value] => sam
          )

 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [key] => E-mail:
      [value] => sam@gmail.com
    )

 [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [key] => Contact no:
        [value] => 4123563210
   )
)
```

Comment: $variableName->key;
$variableName->value;

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string  if i use $variableName->value;

Comment: `$variableName[0]->value` for name like that so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($ur_array as $data){
 echo $data->key . $data->value }
```

Should work.

Comment: how can i post to my mail that keys and values

Comment: $string_to_be_sent = '';    
foreach($ur_array as $data){
    $string_to_be_sent .= $data->key . $data->value ."/r/n" }   put the     $string_to_be_sent as the content of email

Comment: Thank a lot ,Niranjan i was trying this things from three days.